# Broken texture number OpenGL, after glGenTextures/glBindTexture

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I have a terrible behavior with one of my textures on OpenGL.

After deleting a texture, I create a new one, it generates the same tex number as before, but the texture is incorrect. Also glGetError returns always 0 on every line ! I tried to add glFlush/glFinish after glDeleteTextures but it doesn't change anything ! the texture number seems locked somewhere...why ?

It's single threaded, here the behavior :

```
//myTexture == 24 is loaded and works correctly
GLboolean bIsTexture = glIsTexture(myTexture); //returns 1 = > ok
glDeleteTextures(1,&myTexture);
bIsTexture = glIsTexture(myTexture); //returns 0 => ok

//Let's create a new texture
glGenTextures(1,&myTexture);//myTexture == 24 (as the glDelete was ok)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,myTexture);     
bIsTexture = glIsTexture(myTexture); //returns 0 => FAILS
```

Comment: It was a mistake in my copy/paste, now it's ok

Comment: FYI, for testing a case like this, probably good idea to manually set myTexture to a different value (maybe max uint) between the two calls, to be sure that myTexture really is being set to the same number in the second call, rather than "doing nothing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call BindTexture to 0 before creating a texture already bind :

```
//Let's create a new texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0); // free the old bind texture if deleted
glGenTextures(1,&myTexture);//myTexture == 24 (as the glDelete was ok)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,myTexture);     
bIsTexture = glIsTexture(myTexture); //returns 1 => Ok
```

Comment: I had the same issue; OpenGL recycled a texture name (after a delete of old texture and generation of new texture), GL reported no errors, however the texture appeared blank in game. The above fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're missing one important step in the commonly used sequence of operations for creating a new texture: Actually allocating it.

```
//Let's create a new texture

glGenTextures(1,&myTexture);//myTexture == 24 (as the glDelete was ok)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,myTexture);
```

Here you must call either glTexImage2D or glTexStorage to actually allocate the texture object. Before doing so, there's no texture *data* associated with the generated texture *name*. This is important: The value(s) generated by glGenTextures are not *textures*, but texture *names* (i.e. handles) and while OpenGL states that this should be a texture object already, a buggy driver may interpret it wrongly.

```
glTexImage2D(…); // <<<<<
bIsTexture = glIsTexture(myTexture); //returns …
```

#### Update:

As Andon M. Coleman points out (thanks for that), binding a texture name to a texture target makes texture object (associated to said name). So one should expect glIsTexture to return GL_TRUE in that case. Now here's how reality differs from the ideal world of specification: An actual (buggy) driver may be wrongly implemented and assume a name being associated with a texture object only if there's an actual data storage present, so it might be necessary to do the actual allocation to see the effect.

In practice you normally do the storage allocation quite soon after the name allocation. I presume the test suite the implementer of your driver used does not check for this corner case. Time for writing a bug report.

Comment: According to the OpenGL spec. texture names are associated with objects when they are bound. Since `glIsTexture (...)` only tests whether or not the name is associated with a texture, allocating storage for the texture should not matter. The act of binding the texture alone should be enough.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: See my answer update. Note that in even my original answer I left the return value of glIsTexture as something to be determined.

Comment: In fact I already checked with glTexImage2D, the texture is loaded with no error, but when I draw it, it's empty. This can't be a driver issue because it's buggy on Windows AND Android...

Comment: Also if I just call an other glGenTextures after, all is ok. It's just the texture "24" which act like a ghost (can't reuse it, even after glDeleteTextures)

Comment: @Poppyto: Hmm, could it be that the texture is still bound in some texturing unit target when you call glDeleteTextures on it? What happens if you call `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);` before deletion? I've to carefully read into the specification if what you experience is valid behavior then or not. But please give it a try.

Comment: @Poppyto: Okay the specification forbids what you experience: calling glDeleteTextures on a texture name implies that OpenGL enters a state as if glBindTexture(…, 0) would have been called for all texture units targets which it is bound to. So calling glBindTexture(…, newOldID) should create a new texture target. Now I won't rule out an identical bug present in both drivers, but I also suspect, that there's state caching mechanism (could be in that CGL), that goes "oh glBindTexture(…, 24) – that's already bound, I'm not calling glBindTexture with that again".

Comment: Very good idea to Binding to 0, unfortunately, I tried and it's not working...I tried also binding to 0 before and after deletetextures, but it's not better. But I found the solution :

Call Bind on 0 before creatin a new texture like this 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0); 
glGenTextures(1,&texture->_texture);     
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture->_texture);

Comment: @Poppyto: Either way it's a driver bug and you should report it to both parties. This is a tricky little detail you stumbled over there, and I'm not in the least surprised that it was gotten wrong on both platforms.

Comment: @datenwolf : You are correct, it's a bug because the doc says "If a texture that is currently bound is deleted, the binding reverts to 0 (the default texture)" and it's not working : maybe you can try reproduce my problem on your computer ? it's just 10 lines : 

GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1,&tex);     
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);   
GLboolean vIsTexture = glIsTexture(tex);
glDeleteTextures(1,&tex);
glGenTextures(1,&tex);     
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);   
vIsTexture = glIsTexture(tex);
glDeleteTextures(1,&tex);

Comment: @Poppyto: Well, at least on my laptop (I've to check at my workstation at work, yet), the OpenGL driver won't reuse the name, which is a completely valid behavior: The spec says nothing about the numeric values for OpenGL texture names returned by glGenTextures; as long as they're >0 and unique in the texture namespace a OpenGL implementation is conforming. Thee's no need to reuse the smallest unused name or to have a kind of monotonic behavior; if the OpenGL implementation converted the pointer to the internal texture structure to a uintptr_t and returned that, it were valid behavior.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL 1.1 this is maybe the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing `glIsTexture (...)` does is let you know if an OpenGL name (handle) belongs to a texture or not. In fact, OpenGL names are not actually tied to their final purpose until first-use. In the case of your texture name, `glIsTexture` merely checks to see if the name is associated with a texture; this association takes place the first time you call `glBindTexture (...)` using the name. `glIsTexture` does *not* tell you if the name has an asociated data store (e.g. you called `glTexImage2D (...)` or in OpenGL 4+ `glTexStorage (...)`).

Here's an interesting bit of trivia: before OpenGL 3.0, the spec. allowed you to come up with any unused number for an object name and OpenGL would treat it like you had used a `glGen___ (...)` function to generate the name; this can *still* be done in compatibility profiles. That is how unimportant the name generation functions were in the grand scheme of things.

The big takeaway here is that names are given their function upon fist use. More importantly `glIs___ (...)` merely tells you if a name is associated with a particular kind of OpenGL object (not if it is a valid/initialized/... object).

The official explanation of what I just mentioned comes from the OpenGL spec, which states:

> The command:
>
> `void GenTextures( sizei n, uint *textures );`
>
> returns n previously unused texture names in textures. These names are marked as used, for the purposes of GenTextures only, but they acquire texture state and a dimensionality only when they are **first bound**, just as if they were unused.
>
> The binding is effected by calling:
>
> `void BindTexture( enum target, uint texture );`
>
> with target set to the desired texture target and texture set to the unused name. The resulting texture object is a new state vector, comprising all the state and with the same initial values listed in section 8.21 The new texture object bound to target is, and remains a texture of the dimensionality and type specified by target until it is deleted.

Since this is *all* that `glIsTexture (...)` is supposed to do, I would have to assume that this is a driver bug.

Comment: Thank for your answer but it can't be a driver issue because it's buggy on Windows AND Android AND iOS, there must be a trick...!